# Pivot Table: Remove the blank 'year' +/- dropdown row whilst keeping months separated by year

Tags: excel, excel-formula, aggregate, pivot-table

The format of my pivot table (which summarizes 3 years of data) is making down-river calculations very nasty. Is there a way to remove the blank rows created when grouping by month & year?

This is not a one time task, unfortunately - the data could be from any date onwards, but it will always have three years of data (by day) that needs to be averaged by month.

[Pivot Table example, bad rows highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFe7a.jpg)

NOTE - see my last question, if you can't remove the rows

Comment: Fixed - just needed to display the pivot table in tabular form. Pivot Table Design>Report Layout>Tabular

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - just needed to display the pivot table in tabular form. Pivot Table Design>Report Layout>Tabular –